# Can an embedded Derby database be accessed for analysis from a program like MS Access/ExcelP

Tags: java, embedded-database, derby

I would like to access data stored in an embedded Derby database by my Java application from a program like MS Access/Excel, Open Office, etc?
Is there a way of doing this? I guess the only way this could be achieved is if Apache Derby came with an ODBC driver right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [EasySoft ODBC](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc_jdbc_gateway/index.html) driver will do this. It's certified for use with the Sun Java Db (which is what Derby is called when packaged with Java 6).